# Git - understing Merge Conflict

Tags: git, version-control

I am quite new to `GIT` and trying to understand the concept of Merge Conflict.

On certain occasions, I see below message coming while performing `git pull` while on other occasions, it works just fine. I understand `git pull` is a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`.

I want to understand why do I see below message and what should I do to gracefully tackle this.

```
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
".git/MERGE_MSG"
```

Comment: `git pull` is indeed essentially `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or, if so directed, `git rebase` instead of `git merge`).  But this is not a merge conflict, this is your basic commit operation.  You probably should read through a book, or at least an introductory tutorial, here.

Comment: Ok. My confusion here is, I am not performing a commit here. If this message shows up while committing, I can understand. But showing this commit window on `git pull` surprised me.

Comment: Merge creates a merge commit unless it's a fast-forward merge, that's why it asks for commit message.

Comment: As the user whose ID is a number mostly said, a merge—a *real* merge, anyway, not the fake fast-forward kind— *is* a commit.  So you're getting a new commit, that has two parents (vs the kind you get with most `git commit`s which has only one parent).  Again, a good book like Pro Git would help here.